# Problem with Advertisement on my asp.net page

Tags: c#, asp.net, timer, updatepanel

I am creating a website. On few pages, i want to add advertisement-images(images will be change with time interval specified). for that i had used User-Control which contains a timer and Literal.
Time and Image location will come from DataBase. Time is assigned to timer and after that time image will be changed and new image-location and time will come from DB. This works fine. Literal is in UpdatePanel and timer's tick event will be AsyncPostBack.
The problem is when tick event occurs, on login page, it removs password(and if i am typing username then last few characters also) and focus on textbox control while typing. I got patch with javascript but its temporary and i want to find some solution for this problem.
Any Suggestions ? I want image, Time and redirecturl from DB side.
Any other option...?
Thanks in advance....
LeO

Answer (score 0):

Try using jQuery Instead of Update Panel. Its really a good choice.

Check this link below:

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=568

Comment: A good answer contains more than "use jQuery" and a link. Please add more detail as to why the OP should use jQuery.

Comment: I found it matching his requirement. Its his choice to implement. I just gave an idea. And there are many posts which "just" contain links. So its nothing new.

Comment: that's good one but the thing is i cant avoid using time from DB and i have to change image for that particular time...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your whole page is posting back - this could be due to having something in your Page_Load event that will cause the page to change and hence reload.

Comment: If you are losing characters from your username, it sounds like it is posting back and the viewstate only has what was there before the timer hit.  Likewise with the password (these aren't remembered on postback).

Comment: last 2 or 3 characters only..and that in modelpopup extender, username and password is in modelpopup extender...